# How do I configure PHP to have permission to create directories and make files?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that receives uploads and it works fine in mamp, creating directories and receiving files as necessary, but when I move it to the server it errors out saying it can't do either.

[EDIT]
To be clear, the script will received a file and before storing it, it may need to create a directory for that file beneath itself. So the pseudo code would be...

```
$path = getNewPath();
mkdir("./$path", RECURSIVE);
fwrite($path/$newFile);
```

I've chowned the file to apache and given it 777 permissions, but no dice. I'm assuming that there must be some PHP configuration that designates this, but can't figure out where that is.  httpd.conf is lengthy and, having skimmed it, I don't see anything relevant.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but can't figure out what it is.

TIA

Comment: What OS is your server running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script must be able to write to the parent directory in order to create sub directories, so chmod 777 the parent directory, for instance httpdocs/uploads/ or wherever you are storing these files.

Answer (score 1):

chown or chmod 777 the directories where the script wants to write (create) the files and NOT the script itself.

Comment: the script has to create those directories, so, there's no way for me to proactively pre-chown or pre-chmod them

Comment: The script must be able to write to the parent directory in order to create sub directories, so chmod 777 the parent directory, for instance httpdocs/uploads/ or wherever you are storing these files.  Also what error are you getting?  If none, add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to your script.  Do you get a safe_mode restriction error?

Comment: @dredel but u can chmod the webroot's directory (recursively ) first, and then ur script should be able to create those directories and files. additionally use `chmod` and `chown` in your script on the created files and dirs

Comment: @Dr.Dredel, yes as @Rob said, chown or chmod 777 the parent directory where it wants to create the directories. If you want it to create at root, hell, 777 the root itself :)

Comment: you rock... that did it, thanks. Post this as an answer, I'll give you the checkmar

Comment: Better to chown and chmod 755 or chgrp and chmod 775. chmod 777 is too insecure.

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0777);
```