# How to make PHP create Directories and Sub-Directories and be able to Write to them?

Tags: php, permissions, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I configure PHP to have permission to create directories and make files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936852/how-do-i-configure-php-to-have-permission-to-create-directories-and-make-files)

How can I make PHP create Directories and Sub-Directories and be able to Write to them?

My host is telling me that I will need to install suPHP to be able to do that but I would rather not install a Mod on a live site, especially for something that sounds so simple (creating dirs and writing to them).

Basically, I need PHP to be able to create directories and sub-directories within a folder in my web root and then be able to write to those directories and sub-directories.

Also, mkdir() is not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Hm, do you perhaps have some [safe mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php) settings in effect at the moment?

Comment: There is no way you will be able to solve this without understanding filesystem permissions, and from your comments you do not. http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/help/faq/permissions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mkdir()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: I already tried that and it's not working.  Any ideas why?

Comment: First make sure PHP has write permissions on the folder you're trying to create directories in.

Comment: That's where I'm having problems with the host.  How do I give PHP write permissions for that folder?  After it has write permissions, will it be able to create as many directories and sub-directories as it wants and be able to write files to them?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `mkdir('dirname')`? Note that you'll probably need W-permissions on the root-folder, otherwise you won't be able to actually create the new directory.

Comment: mkdir isn't working.   Is there a security risk to making the webroot folder have Write permissions?

Comment: @Programmer You can change the ownership of the directory you want to create / write in to something like `apache` (depending on the user that is running the web-server).

Comment: I'm being told by my Host something about FACL's ?  Do you know what that is about and whether that will resolve it?

Comment: Well, if you're about to create a single dir that needs subdirs, why not 1) make the webroot writeable, 2) create the directory and 3) set it to be unwriteable once again?

Comment: Because it will need to create directories on the fly, so I can't manually be making it writeable and unwriteable...

Comment: Well, as soon as you've gotten write-permissions in the webroot, you create the directory `x` and then you'll be able to create subdirectories in `x` (as long as you don't render the permissions useless by changing owner or something). :-)

Answer (score -1):

suPHP would help you with permission issues, and that's probably your current issue. You may need a combination of [chmod()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) and [mkdir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) to be able to create directories writable by your web user. the permission you'll need on those folders would be 0777.

Comment: Yes, but how would I do that?

Comment: Did you read the docs I linked above for both functions? Start with your first folder and give the 0777 permision to it with chmod(): chmod('./')
Then you can start creating directories with mkdir, and please read the docs so you can use the second param of mkdir function to set the permission when you create the directory.

Comment: -1 You almost NEVER need 777.... bad, dangerous advice.

Comment: @Josh: I agree on that. What would be the right permission? 775? I've seen some hosts that only work with 0777, but that's why i like to use suPHP since it works with 755.

Comment: @oso96_2000 There is no way to tell from his question what the right permission would be. We don't know how his web process runs, what platform he is using, how his folders and files are structured, etc. I hate to mod people down, but I can't think of a good time to use world/group/user read/write/execute. Giving that advice here is particularly bad because the asker will think it worked and not realize the danger he is in for.

Comment: Don't worry, i understand. I should have stated that doing that could be very dangerous. Thank you for pointing it out :)