# Create nested directory in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a nested directory on a web server. The code creates the directory $userID"."_blog_images ok, but not the post_"."$postID"."_images
directory. I'm using a Mac. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
//Create user root image directory if it does not exist
    if (!is_dir("$userID"."_blog_images")){
        mkdir("$userID"."_blog_images");
    }

//Create post image directory if it does not exist
    if (is_dir("$userID"."_blog_images")){
      if (!is_dir("$userID"."_blog_images/post_"."$postID"."_images")){
         mkdir("$userID"."_blog_images/post_"."$postID"."_images", 0777, true);
      }

    }
?>
```

Comment: Do you already have `$userID"."_blog_images"` as dir?

Comment: Yes that is created if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Check out my answer.

Comment: Does PHP (specifically, the user that PHP is running under) have [rights to create that subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936852/how-do-i-configure-php-to-have-permission-to-create-directories-and-make-files)? Also, you may want to [see why the call to mkdir() fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927564/how-to-find-a-reason-when-mkdir-fails-from-php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per provided info in the comment section your you want to create a `sub-dir` in it when the parent `dir` is already present

**So you code must be**

```
<?php
//Create user root image directory if it does not exist
    if (!is_dir($userID."_blog_images/")){
        mkdir($userID."_blog_images");
    }

//Create post image directory if it does not exist
    if (is_dir($userID."_blog_images/")){
        mkdir($userID."_blog_images/post_".$postID."_images", 0777, true);
    }
?>
```

Comment: I can see that I have confused the question as I didn't include the if statement if the sub directory doesn't exist. I do however want to check if the $userID"."_blog_images exists before I create the sub directory post_"."$postID"."_images in side of that. I will amend the code.

Comment: I have run the similar code on my pc and came to know that `/` is not present in the `dir` it doesn't works.So please check my edited code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I have edited the code as you suggested but it's not creating the sub directory.

Comment: Can you tell me why is it `"$userID"."_blog_images"` and not `"$userID_blog_images"`?

Comment: And just a tip that you will not require `if (!is_dir("$userID"."_blog_images/post_"."$postID"."_images")){` because php automatically prevent the duplicates.

Comment: If I use $userID_blog_images the underscores turn the variable $userID into $userID_blog_images variable.

Comment: Ohh i see `$UserID` is the variable don't assign it in `""` check i'll edit my answer.

Comment: And just tell me the values of `$postID` and `UserID`,we are too close to make this work

Comment: I have edited as you said but it is sill not creating the sub directory. $postID is 73 and $userID is 292

Comment: So here what i meant to tell was `$postID = "73/"` and `$userID = "292/"`it should be like this

Comment: Kunal, you are absolutely right. Your answer does work perfectly. I found another problem I had and foolishly I didn't give you the full context. I had your code nested in another if statement that did not evaluate to true so the code couldn't run. Thanks very much for taking the time to help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help you @Youngie2016 :)